# DuckDB pandas pass DataFrame by name easily with IntelliSense support

Tags: python, pandas, visual-studio-code, duckdb

In DuckDB, we have to directly use the DataFrame variable name as a string in the SQL syntax (as shown [here](https://duckdb.org/2021/05/14/sql-on-pandas.html)):

```py
import pandas as pd
import duckdb

mydf = pd.DataFrame({'a' : [1, 2, 3]})
print(duckdb.query("SELECT SUM(a) FROM mydf").to_df())
```

But in VS Code the IntelliSense will not recognise the reference to `mydf` in the second statement, and it will mark `mydf` as unreferenced. And if `mydf` is renamed with IntelliSense, of course the second statement will break. Is there any way to make IntelliSense work?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use the debug f-string syntax to extract the variable name. This works well with IntelliSense because it already recognises the f-string syntax.

````py
import pandas as pd
import duckdb

def main():
    mydf = pd.DataFrame({'a' : [1, 2, 3]})
    print(duckdb.query("SELECT SUM(a) FROM " + df_name(f"{mydf.size=}")).to_df())

def df_name(dbg_str):
    """gets the DataFrame variable name from the debug str minus the ".size"
    attribute before the equals sign
    
    Example:

    ```
    >>> df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [1, 2, 3]})
    >>> df_name(f"{df.size=}")
    "df"
    ```
    """
    return dbg_str[:dbg_str.index(".size=")]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
````